# I want to concatenate arguments of xcodebuild as string, which have space in it ,then run this command

Tags: shell

I'm trying to build xcode project with shell, and now face a problem.
the command **xcodebuild** has many args, and i may use some of them in some cases.
I have a short example here, the **destination** arg has a space in it:

```
build_cmd='xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj'
destination="platform=iOS,name=generic/iOS Device"

if [ $# -ge 1 ];then
build_cmd=${build_cmd}' -destination '${destination}
fi

#echo $build_cmd
$build_cmd
```

but it failed to run, result with:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action 'Device'.
```

What's wrong here? Somebody help?

---

I want to give another example **if you never use xcodebuild** command:

```
filename="a b c.txt"
cmd='vi '${filename}
$cmd    # i wish to open "a b c.txt", but it opens 3 files, a, b, c.txt
```

how to run command with args which have space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BASH FAQ entry #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
#!/bin/bash

build_cmd=(xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj)
destination="platform=iOS,name=generic/iOS Device"

if [ $# -ge 1 ];then
  build_cmd+=(-destination "$destination")
fi

"${build_cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: I have done like yours build_cmd=(xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug)
 destination="'platform=iOS,name=$d_device_name'"
 
 build_cmd+=(-destination "$destination" clean test)

 echo "${build_cmd[@]}"

 "${build_cmd[@]}"

and is printing the valid command i.e xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Shujaat’s iPad' clean test

but gives error on execution xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'

Comment: Problem is if I run this command i.e "xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Shujaat’s iPad' clean test" via command line working perfectly but If I run this via shell script its not working

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042815/xcodebuild-command-in-shell-script-ios