# xcodebuild command in shell script iOS

Tags: ios, bash, shell, command-line, xcodebuild

I have a complete command to deploy the xCode project on real device.

i.e

```
xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Shujaat’s iPad' clean test
```

its working fine using the command line.

**Todo:** *I wanted to execute this command via a shell script.*

here is my complete shell script `deploy.sh` so for.

```
#!/bin/bash
#My First Script

#Info to be configured 


current_path=$(pwd)
appName="jamesApp"
jamesApp_workspace="jamesAppV2.xcworkspace"

echo "Searching for $jamesApp_workspace workspace..."

if [[ $(ls $jamesApp_workspace) ]];     then 
    echo "$jamesApp_workspace found in current directory."


echo "Listing all installed and connected devices..."
instruments -s devices

echo "Copy + Paste from above devices"
echo "specify name of your decice to launch $appName"
read d_device_name

echo "building workspace for $d_device_name..."

build_cmd=(xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug)
destination="'platform=iOS,name=$d_device_name'"

build_cmd+=(-destination "$destination" clean test)

echo "${build_cmd[@]}"
# Here it prints the valid command given above

"${build_cmd[@]}"

else
    echo "$jamesApp_workspace workspace not found"
    echo "Make sure your current path contains the $jamesApp_workspace workspace"
    echo "Place this file i.e deploy.sh within the directory containing $jamesApp_workspace workspace"
fi;
```

**Problem:**
I have done like

```
build_cmd=(xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug)
destination="'platform=iOS,name=$d_device_name'" 
build_cmd+=(-destination "$destination" clean test) 
echo "${build_cmd[@]}"  #Prints valid command
"${build_cmd[@]}"
```

but gives error on execution

```
xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'
```

if I run the above command via command line its working perfectly but If I run this via shell script its not working.

I have referred [I want to concatenate arguments of xcodebuild as string, which have space in it ,then run this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561370/i-want-to-concatenate-arguments-of-xcodebuild-as-string-which-have-space-in-it/25561469#comment61609751_25561469) to concatenate the xcodebuild command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell removes the single quotes in the original command, therefore you should not have any when creating the array either.

Comment: I removed the single quotes from my script. now I am getting this error
xcodebuild: error: Scheme jamesAppV2 is not currently configured for the test action.. this is strange. command executes successfully  from command line

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042815/xcodebuild-command-in-shell-script-ios/37042925?noredirect=1#comment61639456_37042925

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to execute the command in a similar way by passing it via a string. The command works without the double quotes anywhere on the command for me.

example:

```
$ xcodebuild -project ~/ios_projects/example.xcodeproj -scheme Xcode9-XCtest destination id=EBCDFH7S-DCJD-EE8D-DSKDKD78
```